# My program won't calculate the age correctly and won't accept my input

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{    
    int _age;//declare variable
    getAge();//calls function
    welcomeMessage();//calls function

    return 0;   
}

int getAge(int _age)//takes input from user and assigns a value to age
{
    printf("What is your age?\n");
    scanf("%d", &_age);
}

int welcomeMessage(int _age)//prints how old you are
{   
    printf("Welcome, you are %d years old.\n", _age);   
}
```

I keep getting a random number for the age and I need to recognize what I put in for scanf

Comment: just declare _age outside the main() function as global variable or pass it as by ref  as getAge(int &_age) & welcomeMessage(int &_age) to functions

Comment: does it even compiles? getAge function should take _age parameter by pointer (or reference) and read the value from scanf in the pointer argument

Comment: @Sarag it will  compile since there is no function definition in that case default is take in int. If you hit -Wall in gcc (gcc -Wall something.c) that is different story it will show warnings.

Comment: My suggestion to @RondoNumbaNine600 is to read K&R ANSI C Progariming or some online tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Your `int getAge(int _age)` function should be like the following:

```
void getAge(int* _age)
{
   printf("What is your age?\n");
   scanf("%d", _age);
}
```

and in your `main()` function you need to call `int welcomeMessage(int _age)` as the following:

```
int main()
{    
    int _age;               // declare variable
    getAge(&_age);          // calls function
    welcomeMessage(_age);   // calls function

    return 0;
}
```

And actually, a more correct version of your code should be like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getAge(int*);
void welcomeMessage(int);

int main()
{
    int _age;               
    getAge(&_age);          
    welcomeMessage(_age);   
    return 0;
}

void getAge(int* _age)
{
   printf("What is your age?\n");
   scanf("%d", _age);
}

void welcomeMessage(int _age)
{
   printf("Welcome, you are %d years old.\n", _age)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider re-writing `getAge()`.  Be sure to check the result of `scanf()`.

```
int getAge(void) {
  int age;
  printf("What is your age?\n");
  if (1 == scanf("%d", &age)) {
    return age;
  }
  printf("Trouble with input\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: someone told me I could just get rid of my declarations and put welcomeMessage (getAge ()); and put return _age; after scanf()?

Comment: @RondoNumbaNine600 Likely.  Could instead simply do `puts("Welcome, you are 20 years old.");`.  It depends on coding goals.